# In reality, how to assume the distribution of the measurement device?

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian

In Bayesian approach, how  do we assume or find the probability of the measuring device P(x/theta) where x is the observed data and theta is the unknown.

Is this probability the likelihood function?

Comment: Please provide some context for this question. What course? Which topics recently? Hwk problem? Do you know what kind of device? // A prior distribution is typically based on prior knowledge or experience, and you have given no such info in your question. Lacking useful info, you might use a 'noninformative' prior (normal with huge variance, tiny precision). // No the prior distribution is different from the likelihood function, which expresses the data.